# How to retain form values in Struts2?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I have an action say actionA associated with a JSP page say A.jsp and another actionB associated with B.jsp. There's a form on A.jsp. User submits some data which is set in actionA properties. Now user navigates to B.jsp (or any other page for that matter) and then comes back again to A.jsp. The form data in the fields of A.jsp is lost when the user comes back. I want to retain that data.

I cannot use hidden fields since I have a lot of fields and cannot use sessions either. Is there a way in Struts2? If not can you suggest me any other way?

Comment: `sessions` is one way..and `request.setAttribute` and `request.getAttribute` is another way...

Comment: Why you cannot use session? If you want to retain data you need to store it somewhere (e.g. database, session).

Answer (score 1):

When you want to send data from a pagexto another, as you're working on a http protocol you have two ways, use parameters (hidden fields in post submit or url parameters in get) or you have to use session.
If you can't do neither, think about saving your A state on a database and pass only a key that let you retrieve the A state when you are back.
Sorry for the generic answer but it's all I can say if you  don't give more details.